# SQL Server diagramming without affecting changes to database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, diagram

Is there a database diagramming tool for SQL Server 2012 that does not affect the underlying database structure? I have a collection of tables that currently don't have any relationships defined. I would like to diagram the database tables to demonstrate where we should setup some relationships.

I was starting to use the diagramming tool in SSMS 2012, however from what I understand the underlying database will be changed as I add relationships and/or change table structures. I am just looking for a solution to diagram out possible changes rather than implement them.

Also, I am looking to avoid having to type in all the column names since the tables can contain a large number of columns.

Comment: Create a backup with schema only and then make your changes on the backup database with SSMS.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but creating a DAC package failed on my database. From further reading it appears as this is common for DAC.

Comment: I've provided you with a simple three step answer which will help you make a same DB on which you can use the designer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can right click on you DB the choose **Generate Scripts**

[image]

Then click **Next** until you have the option to choose **Advanced**

[image]

Click on **Advanced**, choose what you want to include in your scripts and **Finish** the process.

[image]

Then just run the script generated to create a new exact same DB where you will use the designer.

Comment: That is exactly what I tried (schema only option included) but the scripts fail as described.

Comment: What was the error? I know that Generate Scripts tend to fail if you generate the *.sql in the root of the C: drive.

Comment: My error ... I had issues dealing with the schema of the table objects. But it was my error. I am following your example now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Visio** (prior to Visio 2013) can be used to diagram database tables. Check out the Reverse Engineer option. The instructions [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1389812.aspx?Import%20SQL%20Database%20structure%20into%20Visio%20) should help with creating the diagram. The changes you make can be saved locally without affecting the database.

Comment: This approach is deprecated in new Visio http://blogs.office.com/2012/10/17/uml-and-database-diagrams-in-the-new-visio/ but a nice suggestion.

Comment: I may tryto find an earlier version of Visio. All I currently have is Visio 2013.